# Summation of the one column value of dataframe is not same before and after merge

Tags: python, pandas

i have taken two dataframe and tried the merge function of pandas. Sum of column TEU in dataframe1 is 368. I have done a outer join with indicator as true. After that i have filtered the column "_merge" with values both and left_only. When i done the sum of TEU column, its coming as 371.

I am not able to figure out, how 3 TEU is excess after the outer join with filtered values as both and left_only.

Attaching the datasets, i have used.

Below are the codes. i have ran.

```
subset_df1 = pd.read_excel(r'subset_df1.xlsx')
subset_df2 = pd.read_excel(r'subset_df2.xlsx') 

sum_TEU_df1 = subset_df1['TEU'].sum()

print(sum_TEU_df1)

subset_merge = subset_df1.merge(subset_df2,how = 'outer',indicator=True)

sum_TEU_df1_after_merge = subset_merge['TEU'][subset_merge._merge!='right_only'].sum()

print(sum_TEU_df1_after_merge)
```

Expected sum was 368 when filtering out right_only and adding remaining values.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data it is hard to say, but there may be a duplicate in the matching column.  Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": list("ABCDEF"),
    "B": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
    })
#    A  B
# 0  A  1
# 1  B  2
# 2  C  3
# 3  D  1
# 4  E  2
# 5  F  3

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": list("ABCDAFG"),
    "C": [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 1]
    })
#    A  C
# 0  A  5
# 1  B  6
# 2  C  7
# 3  D  1
# 4  A  2
# 5  F  3
# 6  G  1

merged = df.merge(df1, how="outer", indicator=True)
#    A    B    C      _merge
# 0  A  1.0  5.0        both
# 1  A  1.0  2.0        both
# 2  B  2.0  6.0        both
# 3  C  3.0  7.0        both
# 4  D  1.0  1.0        both
# 5  E  2.0  NaN   left_only
# 6  F  3.0  3.0        both
# 7  G  NaN  1.0  right_only
```

The sum of `df` column `B` is 12.

When merged on outer, the value in row `A` is repeated (because there is are two `A` values in `df1`).  This means that there is an additional value of 1 in the `merged.sum()` in column B.

It may be that something similar is in your two dataframes.